# zip list with a single element

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of some elements, e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and a single object, e.g. `'a'`. I want to produce a list of tuples with the elements of the list in the first position and the single object in the second position: `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]`.

I could do it with `zip` like this:

```
def zip_with_scalar(l, o): # l - the list; o - the object
    return list(zip(l, [o] * len(l)))
```

However, this gives me a feeling of creating and unnecessary list of repeating element.

Another possibility is

```
def zip_with_scalar(l, o):
    return [(i, o) for i in l]
```

which is very clean and pythonic indeed, but here I do the whole thing "manually". In Haskell I would do something like

```hs
zipWithScalar l o = zip l $ repeat o
```

Is there any built-in function or trick, either for the zipping with scalar or for something that would enable me to use ordinary zip, i.e. sort-of infinite list?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat

Comment: What jonrsharpe said, but also you probably want to rewrite that as a generator, rather than a regular function.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity as the OP is using 3.x they can just `return zip(l, repeat(o))`; it's an iterator, no need to `yield`.

Comment: Good point, I missed the tag.

Comment: Just be careful with mutable values for o or you may get some surprises

Comment: @jonrsharpe that page you linked... The first table states count function can have either one or two arguments, "start" being non-optional. But above the table there is a map-count example in which it takes zero arguments. Looks inconsistent...

Comment: @Arioch'The the docs show that both arguments have default values, but if you think there's room for improvement tell the Python bug tracker, not me!

Comment: I do not have account there, but someone here probably does.  Lik I told look at the first table there `Infinite Iterators:    count()     start, [step]` - as you can see `start` is marked as mandatory and only `step` is marked as optional. While detailed description of the function indeed shows both arguments of equal class (mandatory with defaults), the top table shows different

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is the cloest to your Haskell solution:

```
import itertools

def zip_with_scalar(l, o):
    return zip(l, itertools.repeat(o))
```

You could also use generators, which avoid creating a list like comprehensions do:

```
def zip_with_scalar(l, o):
    return ((i, o) for i in l)
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use the built-in `map` function:

```
>>> elements = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> key = 'a'
>>> map(lambda e: (e, key), elements)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a perfect job for the [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) class.

```
from itertools import cycle


def zip_with_scalar(l, o):
    return zip(i, cycle(o))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(zip(l, cycle('a')))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]
```

Comment: The argument to ``cycle`` must be an iterable, doesn't it? It works with ``'a'`` as it is string, but not with an arbitrary object.

Comment: @zegkljan yes it must be an iterable.

Comment: Only if the object to map to is an iterable of length one, `cycle` gives the result this question is asking for. If you do the same for the string `'ab'` instead of `'a`' you get the following: `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'b')]`

Comment: string are iterable if you want to return the string indefinitely you should put this into a container. `list` will do fine. `list(zip(range(20), cycle(["ab"])))` @Swier

Answer (score 8):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
tups = [(itm, 'a') for itm in lst]
tups

> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]
```

Answer (score 7):

```py
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(zip(l, "a"*len(l)))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use *zip_longest* with a `fillvalue` of `o`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def zip_with_scalar(l, o): # l - the list; o - the object
    return zip_longest(l, [o], fillvalue=o)

print(list(zip_with_scalar([1, 2, 3, 4] ,"a")))
```

Just be aware that any mutable values used for `o` won't be copied whether using zip_longest or repeat.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one came up with a simple Pythonic solution using list comprehension or a generator object.

Take that we have a list of strings -> data
And we want to use zip() by adding a single integer 2001 (year) to each item.
We can create a list that has the same length as the data list and contains the integer 2001 in each item.

```py
data = ['RIN1', 'RIN2', 'RIN3', 'RIN4', 'RIN5', 'RIN6', 'RIN7']
zipped = list(zip(data, [2001 for _ in data]))
```

**But** there's an even better solution using a generator - thus we can avoid creating a potentially huge list of the same value.

```py
data = ['RIN1', 'RIN2', 'RIN3', 'RIN4', 'RIN5', 'RIN6', 'RIN7']
zipped = list(zip(data, (2001 for _ in data)))
```

So instead of creating the actual list with `[2001 for _ in data]`
we can define a generator object: `(2001 for _ in data)`

The difference (on the surface) is only the type of brackets: [...] -> (...)

I hope some of you find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

The [`more-itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) library recently added a [`zip_broadcast()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.zip_broadcast) function that solves this problem well:

```
>>> from more_itertools import zip_broadcast
>>> list(zip_broadcast([1,2,3,4], 'a'))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]
```

This is a much more general solution than the other answers posted here:

- Empty iterables are correctly handled.
- There can be multiple iterable and/or scalar arguments.
- The order of the scalar/iterable arguments doesn't need to be known.
- If there are multiple iterable arguments, you can check that they are the same length with `strict=True`.
- You can easily control whether or not strings should be treated as iterables (by default they are not).

Answer (score 0):

Just define a class with infinite iterator which is initialized with the single element you want to injected in the lists:

```
class zipIterator:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.__val = val

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.__val
```

and then create your new list from this class and the lists you have:

```
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4]
key = 'a'
res = [it for it in zip(elements, zipIterator(key))]
```

the result would be:

```
>>res
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')]
```