# Zip list with several elements

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I am trying to enhance [`zip_with_scalar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36536197/2350145) logic. I am trying to zip with a *vector*

So far I have achieved this -

```
import itertools

def zip_with_vector(l, o):
    if not isinstance(o, list):
        return zip(l, itertools.repeat(o))
    else:
        for e in o:
            l = list(zip_with_vector(l, e))

    return l

print(list(zip_with_vector(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z'])))

>>> [((('a', 'x'), 'y'), 'z'), ((('b', 'x'), 'y'), 'z'), ((('c', 'x'), 'y'), 'z')]
```

but I want as this `[('a', 'x', 'y', 'z'), ('b', 'x', 'y', 'z'), ('c', 'x', 'y', 'z')]`

I know I am close but not able to figure out the recursion logic.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Can you explain in words what you want your function to do?

Comment: for this example data you need `def zip_with_vector(l, o): return [[x] + o for x in l]`

Comment: He wants more like this: `def zip_with_vector(l, o): return [tuple(x) + tuple(o) for x in l]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a sequence of "each element of the input list, concatenated with the input vector", then write just that:

```py
def zip_with_vector(l, v):
  return ((elem,) + tuple(v)
          for elem in l)

list(zip_with_vector(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']))
>>> [('a', 'x', 'y', 'z'), ('b', 'x', 'y', 'z'), ('c', 'x', 'y', 'z')]
```

If this is indeed what you're looking for, then I don't see a need for recursion here.

As @Georgy mentioned in the comments, this can be written more concisely (and will probably execute faster) thus:

```py
def zip_with_vector(l, v):
  return ((elem, *v) for elem in l)
```

Comment: You can also write it a bit more concise as `return ((elem, *v) for elem in l)`

Comment: @Georgy Very true! I forget Python3 has the cool sequence unpacking syntax. This will probably also be somewhat faster than my approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend [`zip_with_scalar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36536197/7851470) to `zip_with_vector` by mapping `itertools.repeat` to each element of the vector:

```
def zip_with_vector(iterable, vector):
    return zip(iterable, *map(itertools.repeat, vector))
```

```
>>> list(zip_with_vector(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']))
[('a', 'x', 'y', 'z'), ('b', 'x', 'y', 'z'), ('c', 'x', 'y', 'z')]
```