# Iterate a List and add the value to the List which is in Dictionary and clean it for every Iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I  have a python dictionary and a python list.

```
dictionary=
{
 "a":"A",
 "b":"B",
 "c":"C",
 "Test":[]
}
```

I also have a python list,

```
list=["1","2","3","4"]
```

How  Can I generate

```
[{
 "a":"A",
 "b":"B",
 "c":"C",
 "Test":["1"]
},
{
 "a":"A",
 "b":"B",
 "c":"C",
 "Test":["2"]
},
{
 "a":"A",
 "b":"B",
 "c":"C",
 "Test":["3"]
},
{
 "a":"A",
 "b":"B",
 "c":"C",
 "Test":["4"]
}]
```

Spare  me If it is a  silly question.

Comment: You can generate this with a loop. Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36536171/zip-list-with-a-single-element

Answer (score 1):

there's a few steps and some ideas here, but broadly

- start a fresh list to pack the final results into
- iterate over the list (lists are already iterable)
- copy the dict at each cycle (otherwise it'll manipulate the original one)

```py
list_dest = []
for member in list_src:
    sub_dict = dict_src.copy()  # must copy.deepcopy for deeper members
    sub_dict["Test"] = [member]  # new list with only the list member
    list_dest.append(sub_dict)

# list_dest is now the desired collection
```

additionally

- don't override builtins like `list`, as it can become confusing when you attempt to reference them later
- if you wanted to get more depth than the top contents of the source dict, you should use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), or you'll still have [references to the original members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this in short line is the following code:

```py
my_list = ["1","2","3","4"]
dictionary={"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C","Test":[]}

list_of_dictionnaries = []

for e in my_list:
    dictionary["Test"] = [e]
    list_of_dictionnaries.append(dictionary.copy())

print(list_of_dictionnaries)
```

`list` is a built-in function, you should never name your variables as built-in functions, instead, name it something like `my_list`, or `my_indices`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dictionary= {
 "a":"A",
 "b":"B",
 "c":"C",
 "Test":[]
}
list=["1","2","3","4"]

result = []
for item in list:
    single_obj = dictionary.copy()
    single_obj["Test"] = [item]
    result.append(single_obj)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
   {
      "a":"A",
      "b":"B",
      "c":"C",
      "Test":[
         "1"
      ]
   },
   {
      "a":"A",
      "b":"B",
      "c":"C",
      "Test":[
         "2"
      ]
   },
   {
      "a":"A",
      "b":"B",
      "c":"C",
      "Test":[
         "3"
      ]
   },
   {
      "a":"A",
      "b":"B",
      "c":"C",
      "Test":[
         "4"
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: You shouldn't name a list list in pyhton as it is a built-in function

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
dictionary={
 "a":"A",
 "b":"B",
 "c":"C",
 "Test":[]
}
l_=[]
list2=["1","2","3","4"]
for i in list2:
    dict1=dictionary.copy() #==== Create a copy of the dictionary 
    dict1['Test']=[i] #=== Change Test value of it.
    l_.append(dict1) #=== Add the dictionary to l_
print(l_)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {c: c.upper() for c in 'abc'}
L = [d.copy() for _ in range(4)]
for i, d in enumerate(L):
    d['Test'] = [str(i+1)]
```